# Laravel class constructor must accept collection of models

Tags: laravel, collections, laravel-collection

Is there a way for a class constructor to validate that input parameter is a collection of certain objects?

I know I can do:

```
public function __construct(Collection $input)
```

But is it possible to force it has to be a collection of a given objects(models)? 
Something like:

```
public function __construct(Collection<User> $input)
```

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible. One way to do this would be to check the contents of the collection inside the constructor (or create a method that performs the check and call that inside the constructor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not support generics so the short answer is no.

---

However when googling for "php typed arrays" you will find a bunch of packages which will allow you to do what you want by creating a custom class that only accepts the types you want and you are able to type hint those. But for custom types you will need to create your own class that only accepts values of a certain type.

I quite like [this](https://medium.com/2dotstwice-connecting-the-dots/creating-strictly-typed-arrays-and-collections-in-php-37036718c921) post and the ideas suggested in there.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no it cannot be done.

PHP allocates memory dynamically and what's more, it doesn't care what sort of object you store in your collection (or array).

For someone that is used to languages like java this may be pretty strange.
This provides flexibility as you can store any kind of object or variable you want in your collection, but at the same time it may lead to unexpected behaviour..